# Converting dateTime to different format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

There is a `dateTime` in the format of "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt". A `string` is required to be created from this, in the format of "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff".

```
string timestamp = (dateTimeUTC.Year).ToString() +  (dateTimeUTC.Month).ToString() + (dateTimeUTC.Day).ToString() + (dateTimeUTC.Hour).ToString() + (dateTimeUTC.Minute).ToString() +
                           (dateTimeUTC.Second).ToString() + (dateTimeUTC.Millisecond).ToString();
```

The problem with this code is that if any of the digits for month or day are 0-9, there is no 0 in front of the digit. For example, suppose we have the `dateTime` 1/26/2020 11:59:53 PM. This must be converted to 20200126235651100. Instead it will be 20201262359530.

Comment: Some reason you can’t use `string.Format()` or `ToString`?

Comment: Basically everyone has the same answer.

Comment: I developed a twitch after reading that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the format on `ToString`

```cs
string timestamp = dateTimeUTC.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.ToString()` with required format, Like

```
string timestamp = dateTimeUTC.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
Console.WriteLine(timestamp);   //2020126235953000
```

But as per your requirement you need `timestamp` should convert to `20201262359530`, if you notice you need only one digit of seconds fraction, so do not use `fff` three times, use below format which will give you exact value which is mentioned in your question.

```
string timestamp = dateTimeUTC.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssf");
Console.WriteLine(timestamp);   //20201262359530
```

Input:

```
dateTimeUTC: 1/26/2020 11:59:53 PM
```

Output:

```
20201262359530
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HfXiu6)

Answer (score 1):

Jsut use the [DateTime Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (which you even have in your question):

```
var x = DateTime.Parse("1/26/2020 11:59:53 PM");    
var result = x.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
```